# Error numerical differentiation - how to interpret constant/variable

Tags: real-analysis

Im basically looking for help explaning the symbols in this problems. Mores specifically: what does $C^3$  and $d$ mean exactly. How do I interpret them?

Let $f ∈ C^3$ [a, b]. Let $d ∈ N$ and let $ξ_1, . . . , ξ_d ∈ [a, b]$. Show that there exists $ξ ∈ [a, b]$ with

$ f''' (ξ) = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{j=1}^{d} f'''(ξ_j) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C^3[a,b]$ is the set of triply continuously differentiable functions defined on $[a,b]$ (meaning that $f'''$ is continuous). $d$ is the number of points chosen in $[a,b]$. The theorem is a consequence of the intermediate value theorem, applied to $f'''$.

Let $m$ and $M$ be the smallest and largest of the $f'''(\xi_k)$.

- the average of the $f'''(\xi_k)$ is certainly in $[m,M]$.
- by the IVT, there is always a $\xi$ such that $f'''(\xi)$ equals a given value in $[m,M]$.

[image]